# Get all points from pointcloud where pointcloud is new Potree.PointCloudOctree(geometry)

Tags: point-clouds

I use potree to view my model i want to get list of all points in pointcloud to add event to each point depending on its index. Can I get list of all points without using measurement tools ?
i want to get points from pointcloud

```js
 Potree.loadPointCloud(cloudPointsPath, "name", e => {
                var pointcloud = e.pointcloud;
                var material = pointcloud.material;
                viewer.scene.addPointCloud(pointcloud);
                material.pointColorType = Potree.PointColorType.RGB;
                material.size = 1;
                material.pointSizeType = Potree.PointSizeType.FIXED;
                material.shape = Potree.PointShape.PARABOLOI;
                viewer.fitToScreen();
            });
```

Comment: Is this requirement applicable if not how can i add event on points and get clicked point

Comment: i believe you have posted your question under the wrong tag. `potree` is written on top of `webgl` not `three.js`

Comment: @gaitat i edited the question to be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got list of points using this code

```js
 function getAllPointsOfPointCloud(pointCloud) {
            var list = [];
            var array = pointCloud.pcoGeometry.root.geometry.attributes.position.array;
            var index = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < pointCloud.pcoGeometry.root.geometry.attributes.position.length;i=i+3) {
                var x = array[i + 0];
                var y = array[i+ 1];
                var z = array[i + 2];
                let position = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
                position.applyMatrix4(pointCloud.matrixWorld);
                list[index] = position;
                index++;
            }
            return list;
        }
```